# Overriding Exceptions in Java

Tags: java, exception

```
public class Student {

    checkAge (Student student) {
        try {
            if (student.getAge() > 18 ) {
                throw new CustomException("Student is older than 18 years.");
            }
        } catch (CustomException e) {
            handleException(e);
        }
    } 


public class HandleException {
    public static sendToErrorReport (CustomException customException) {
        //trying to do something like this, but the below code throws an error.
        customException.setMessage(customException.getMessage() +" ; Student -> " + customException.getStudent().getStudentName);
    }
}
```

I've created a custom class for handling exceptions that occur in my project. My requirement is to change the message for the exception and append some data to the exception message and pass it to my custom class.

So essentially I need to edit the exception message once it has already been set.

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: post an example code?

Comment: To understand correctly: (1) to catch an exception and rethrow an other exception, or (2) throw a child exception with an `@Override getMessage() { return super.getMessage() + ... }`?

Answer (score 0):

you can override `getMessage` method of `Exception` class

```
class CustomException extends java.lang.Exception{

    @Override
    public String getMessage(){
        return super.getMessage() + "- My Message";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code when it throws exception

```java
try{
//Some code here
}catch(Exception e){
 throw new CustomeException("Your text here")
}
```

When you catch CustomeException in some other place you can modify same.

```java
try{
//Some code here
}catch(CustomException e){
String message = e.getMessage();
//Do stuff with previous message
 throw new Custom2Exception("Your next text here")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full CustomException class which extends RuntimeException Class. You can define code and message.

```
public class CustomException extends RuntimeException {

    private String code;
    private String message;

    public CustomException() {
        super();
    }

    public CustomException(Exception e) {
        super(e);
    }

    public CustomException(String code, String message, Exception e) {
        super(message, e);
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```